# MongoDB database. Error "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I have installed MongoDB in my Django project. Because is the first time I use Mongo, I decided to try how it works and I created a simple program to store data ( price and quantity in my case).
The project is called "exchange" and it has 2 folders: exchange and app.

This is the file models.py from 'app' folder:

```
from django.db import models
from djongo.models.fields import ObjectIdField, Field
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    #ips = models.Field(default=[])
    #subprofiles = models.Field(default={})
```

This is the file admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Profile)
admin.site.register(Order)
```

This is how I set the database in the file settings.py of the exchange folder

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'engine',
    }
}
```

So after made the migrations and create the superuser, I run the server, I went into the section Admin than in Profile, and I created a profile choosing the only option available (my superuser).
At this point I created an order in the Orders section: so I chose in the "profile" field the only option available (the profile created before), then I filled the other 2 fields (price and quantity), but when I try to save it, appears above the field "profile" the following error:

"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

I cannot understand where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `ForeignKey` by default appends `_id` to the property name.  In your above example, it is trying to use the property `user_id` on Profile and `profile_id` on Order.

The solution is to update the ForeignKey to:

```
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, db_column='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What you change `db_column` to may depend on how you have your schema set up inside mongodb, but I was receiving this same error and point the `db_column` to the correct property fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

OMG @Adam Berg , I have been trying to resolve this issue for more than past 4 hours .Your answer resolved it within in mints .Thank you so much , your work is much appreciable.

```
import datetime,os
from djongo import models

class test1(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(test1, db_column='user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This Will help you to perform all the foreign key related Query.