# How can I fix this error "premium is not one of valid choices please select valid choice" from drop down in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Context:

I was able to set a user to PREMIUM from the admin panel but after resetting the database I see this error. I'm unable to figure out what's going on or how to fix it.

The error is: "Select a valid choice. PREMIUM is not one of the available choices".

Here is code for my Profile class:

```
  class Profile(models.Model): 
        PREMIUM_CHOICES = (("FREE",0),("PREMIUM",1))
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        premium = models.IntegerField(choices=PREMIUM_CHOICES,default=0)
        due_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

I've looked at several answers on Stackoverflow:
[MongoDB database. Error "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643818/mongodb-database-error-select-a-valid-choice-that-choice-is-not-one-of-the-av)

Here is screen capture of the error:

[image]

Comment: swap the tuple choices, so `PREMIUM_CHOICES = ((0, "FREE"),(1, "PREMIUM"))`

Comment: thank you so much, this worked. If you create answer I will select as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation on the [**`choices=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) says:

> A sequence consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g.
> `[(A, B), (A, B) …]`) to use as choices for this
> field. If choices are given, they’re enforced by model validation and
> the default form widget will be a select box with these choices
> instead of the standard text field.
>
> The **first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the
> model**, and the second element is the human-readable name.

The first item is thus the key (here an `int`) and the second a human-readable name of that value. The choices thus should be:

```
PREMIUM_CHOICES = ((0, 'FREE'),(1, 'PREMIUM'))
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).